# Is there a term for computer users who prefer keyboard shortcuts over a mouse?

Tags: phrase-requests, computing

Loosely, this person could be called a "superuser" or "power user" but those are broad terms that don't specifically refer to a user who avoids a computer's mouse or trackpad.

Over at the superuser stackexchange, their [community tag description for "keyboard shortcut"](https://superuser.com/tags/keyboard-shortcuts/info) uses 22 words to describe this profile. (I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1544892/is-there-a-name-for-users-who-prefer-keyboard-shortcuts-over-the-mouse) there but was referred here.)

All I can think of are generic terms like "hotkey enthusiast", but that got me wondering whether we have a specific word for this type of person.

Comment: ... Murophobes?

Comment: Why does there have to be a "term"? What's wrong with 'person who prefers to use the keyboard"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey re your Q1: that's a reasonable pushback. I don't have an extensive vocabulary myself, but after trying many times to refer to this person I have not found a succinct and precise way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey re "person who prefers to use the keyboard" --> I don't think it's precise enough. When people design software they often require a mouse-click to perform tasks. However, many (or all?) of these tasks could be performed with only a keyboard and no mouse, but only if the software designers allow for it. It's a very specific category of human-computer interaction I would define more tightly than just "prefer to use keyboard" because it has nothing to do with people who prefer keyboard over using voice or gestures to perform tasks.

Comment: @andytilia - "I have not found a succinct and precise way to do it." This could be, as my question was meant to imply, that the existing ways of expressing the idea are as succinct and precise as they need to be. If someone is discussing Excel find and replace with me, and it becomes clear, with all their dragging and clicking, that they only know how to interact with the application using a mouse, I might say "Oh I just do Control-F. _I prefer to use the keyboard for some things_". I don't feel the need to use a noun for that.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking this person would be a *Typist*, a long lost profession. In today's nomenclature they may be called either a *manualist*, for using their hands rather than their wrist. Though a more specific term for their use of fingers might be a *Digitalist*.

Since they are not typing words so much as hot-keying or keyboarding rather than mousing they could be described as a *Keyboardist*. This would be distinct from a *Typist* who types words. A Keyboardist is instead one who accomplishes their text and screen manipulations using the hot-key combinations available on the keyboard.

I think one who accomplishes these things by pawing and scratching with the mouse might be called a *Mouser*, what used to be a respectable term for a cat that might actually take the initiative in catching tiny rodents.

Comment: Hi Elliot, thanks for your reply. I like _manualist_ if it's clear that it's referring to hands rather than wrists (which I didn't realize til now). In your second paragraph, I don't fully understand how _keyboardist_ would refer more to hot-keying than typing words -- can you say a little more about what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I know not an exact match but perhaps you could say “command-line user” as opposed to “GUI user”.

I know that the OP is asking about hot keys etc, but the people who use them are same people who are drawn to CLI and terminal instead of GUI and WIMP.

From [BBC computer science](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zr9kw6f/revision/2) resources for students:

> There are two main types of interface:
>
> - graphical user interface (GUI) - sometimes known as WIMP (Windows, Icons, Menus, Pointers) interface
> - command line interface (CLI).
>
> […]
>
> Command line interfaces
> CLIs are text-based. Users control the computer by typing in commands.
> […]